# Using unsigned values for ID field?

Tags: sql, int

I just realized, that noone, I've ever seen is using unsigned for the ID field, in databases?

Wouldn't it be logical to use unsigned values for ID? Since ID fields is 1+ and auto increment?

Using `SMALLINT` for example, would give signed -32767 to 32767. While 0 to 65535?

Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in most cases it doesn't matter. Many databases don't hit 2 billion rows and certainly won't hit 4 billion rows (assuming 32-bit integers, that is; I haven't seen anyone using `smallint` for IDs).

Then there are databases that require globally unique IDs which don't use `int` at all but GUIDs. Signedness obviously is even less of an issue there.

Comment: How big is the performance difference for a lot of SELECT calls? `smallint` is 2 bytes, as far as I know. And `int` is 4 bytes?

Comment: Measure it. I don't know. But I suspect it doesn't matter very much in 99.99 % of the cases. But this question wasn't about performance, was it?

Comment: No, although it originated from me creating a database, trying to make it as lightweight as possible.